# Phishing/Spam using old MX record for direct sending which is circumventing Mimecast

Tags: email, exchange

We've been using Mimecast for email security for a few months now and there's been a dozen or so incidents where the phish/spam senders have utilized the old MX records to send directly to our Office 365 users which is circumventing Mimecast completely.

It's written about in a blog post where the writer dubs it "Direct Spooling": [Iron Bastion - How to Evade Expensive Phishing Filters with One Simple Trick](https://blog.ironbastion.com.au/how-to-evade-expensive-phishing-filters-with-one-simple-trick-report-part-1/) and is addressed by Mimecast in their knowledgebase article at [Locking Down Your Office 365 Inbound Email Flow](https://community.mimecast.com/docs/DOC-2115).

What I'd like to know is if there is a way to redirect instead of reject the emails so we can determine if there are any legitimate emails coming via this method (eg. from on-premise multifunction devices).

Could a Mail Flow rule achieve the same as the inbound connector by detecting last hop IP's and redirecting anything not from the specified IP's to a shared mailbox that admins can review?

Comment: Being Office365 (specifically Exchange Online) I wasn't sure where I would ask this question - I went for here because it's about trying to protect against malicious activities.  An Exchange Online Mail Flow Rule can be used to detect and action emails based on a number of patterns (sender info, recipient info, message envelope info).  One of the actions most definitely is the ability to redirect - to stop the email going to it's intended mailbox and being sent somewhere else.

Comment: What you describe is not a redirect, i.e telling the sender to use a different recipient. What you describe instead is forwarding, i.e. accepting the mail but sending it to a different than the original recipient.

Comment: No, a forward implies that it reached its addressed recipient and is passed on to the intended recipient.  The mail flow rule processes the email in transit at the server BEFORE it is routed to any mailbox - thus it is a redirect.

Think of a person who has moved house and purchases a mail redirect at the local post office.  The letter is processed by the handler who shunts it into a PO Box or wherever it is redirected to.  If it was a forward, it would still have to go to the mailbox of the recipient (that may or may not be there) where it is handled and bounced back or forwarded on.

Comment: tomayto tomarto though - what you call it is irrelevant to the question.  A mail flow rule can be used to intercept mail and action it - the question is if there one of these rules can be used to emulate what the inbound connector does to only deliver email to the intended recipient if it passed through the Mimecast servers, everything else gets sent to another mailbox for review.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a good reason, you should lock down your 'old' IP's at the firewall so that un-trusted connections cannot send at all.

I'm assuming that you are talking about MX records that no longer exist? Otherwise they should be removed, or possibly pointed at Mimecast if that is possible.

Comment: This Exchange environment is Office 365's Exchange Online. It's not hard to guess a tenancy's hard MX that can't be deleted per-se. Usually something like domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com. I've used the Mimecast IP's AND all of our site's static IP's in the inbound connector. But I was hoping there'd be a way to emulate the connector with a Mail Flow Rule.